# Keyboard doesn't work with Tor Browser

Tags: tor, vidalia

I use the actual Tor Browser 2.3.25-14 and Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander). I start Tor in the command-line window (`./start-tor-browser`).

The cable less keyboard and mouse (Logitech) are working, the Vidalia control panel opens, after having connected to the Tor network, the Tor Browser window (Firefox) opens automatically. The onion is green, everything ok. But the keyboard doesn't work in the Tor Browser window, the mouse, yes, does work.

When I close Tor with the Vidalia control panel and open another application, the keyboard works again. Is there somebody who can help me or at least understands the problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 29):

You don't need to remove `ibus`, as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/377302/147044) says, since you may need it! The correct solution is very simple and consists in:

1. Open `start-tor-browser` script file from inside the Tor package with your favorite editor. I use `gedit` for shell scripts, so, in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), you can use the following command:

   ```
   gedit /path/to/start-tor-browser
   ```
2. Add the following line on the second line (immediately after the line containing shebang interpreter directive - `#!/bin/sh`):

   ```
   export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
   ```

   The above line change the default value (`ibus` - Intelligent Input Bus, an input method framework for multilingual input) for `GTK_IM_MODULE` environment variable (which specifies an input method module to use) to `xim` (X Input Method).
3. Of course, save the file and close it.
4. Close Tor and reopen it.

That's all (until [this bug](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9353) will be  fixed properly)!

Comment: How can I find the path to tor-browser?

Comment: @mahdiar Run these commands: `sudo updatedb`, then `locate start-tor-browser`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what this line we are adding actually does?

Comment: adding export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" to start-tor-browser works great for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the version 3.5.3 this bug has been fixed!

I tested it under Ubuntu 13.10 64 bits and didn't need of any modification, it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was sufficient to exit ibus by doing:

```
ibus exit
```

[Further details are available on the FAQ of the Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#UbuntuBlackedOut).

Answer (score -1):

This bug is fixed in TOR forum: [#9353 (Keyboard does not work in 64-bit TBB 2.3.25-10 and 3.0 when ibus is running)
     – Tor Bug Tracker & Wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9353)

Just need to remove the `ibus` package (it provides an input interface for complex writing languages). I hope you don't need it.

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus
```

And then restart your display manager

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: This is not a fix or a solution since someone may need ibus.